# {"error": {"extra": -2147483648, "what": 1}} error while playing .mpd dash files in react -native Android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, drm, react-native-video

I have used react-native-video to play DRM content with .mpd extension. But it is giving me an error 
{"error": {"extra": -2147483648, "what": 1}}

My video-player is like :

```
         onBack={this.goBack}
         videoInfo={toJS(videoDetails)}
         videoUrl={dashUrl}
         source={{
           uri: url,
           drm: {
             type: "widevine",
             licenseServer: [licence_server]",
              headers: {
                customdata: xml,
              },
            },
          }}
        />
```

There is not any error or urls as it is being played in DRM test site.
The above video player uses RNVideo so there is also not an issue as it plays other normal mp4 files.
What can be the error?
Is it a library issue or what?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be an error that others have seen also.

The usual advice for React Native video playback on Android at this time is make the app use ExoPlayer rather than the Android default player as it seems to give a better experience.

ExoPlayer is a a Google developed Media player for Android and is the usually the standard for a native (i.e. Java or Kotlin) app needing to play back audio and video, at the time of writing.

It appears there may be an issue with 'autolinking' the ExoPlayer library (https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/issues/1894#issuecomment-584832293) - the suggested workaround to force your app to use ExoPlayer rather than the default player is, reproduced here from a solution to the issue above:

```js
module.exports = {
  dependencies: {
    'react-native-video': {
      platforms: {
        android: {
          sourceDir: '../node_modules/react-native-video/android-exoplayer',
       },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Place the above in your root directory for your app and name it react-native.config.js

There are also reports that characters in the filename in the url may cause the error code you are seeing - see the note here about removing underscores (in fact worth looking at the full tread of this issue): https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/issues/1186#issuecomment-552738393

Comment: This is bang on. Worked great. Well-written answer, too.

Comment: I'm trying to stream m3u8 files and this solution just causes another error: `{"error": {"errorException": "com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error", "errorString": "Unrecognized media format"}}`